# android json object some issue in code not able to get the json array from php

Tags: android, json

I cant get the following array object from the php side

```
{"result":"sucess","data":["Painting service","Plumbing service", 
"Electrical service","Carpentry Services","Aluminium works",
"House Cleaning","Home Appliance","Glazing Cleaning",
"Yard Maintenance","Water Tank Cleaning",
"Electronics Services","Upholstery Services","DRY CLEANERS",""],"msg":" Sucessfull"}
```

this is my json responce from php side

and im using

```
   protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                List<NameValuePair> userpramas = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                //String a =(spinerplan.getSelectedItem().toString());
                userpramas.add(new BasicNameValuePair("package_type",glbstr_plan));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CommonClass.SERVIVECS_URL, "POST",
                        userpramas);
                //Log.e("testing", "json url value=" + json);
                try {

                    String responce = json.getString("data");

                    JSONObject servicejson = new JSONObject(responce);
                    JSONArray jArray = servicejson.getJSONArray("data");

                    System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jArray.length());

                    for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.e("testing", "responce" + json_data);
                    }




                    Log.e("testing", "responce" + responce);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return responce;
            }
```

Comment: nothing is coming as value in log e

Comment: $services=mysql_query("select service_name from services");
  $ser='';
  while($fservices=mysql_fetch_array($services))
  {
   $ser.=$fservices['service_name'].",";
  }
  $newser = explode($ser,",");
  print_r($newser);
  
  echo "<br/>".$ser."<br/>";
  
  if(mysql_num_rows($services))
   { 
    $arr = array('result' => "sucess", 'data' => $ser, 'msg' => ' Sucessfull');
   
   }
        
   else
   {
    $arr = array('result' => "error",  'msg' => 'Unsucessfull');
   }
  
 
   echo json_encode($arr);     
 
   

?>

Comment: is there any problem in php side

Comment: check `SERVIVECS_URL` directly in your browser with parameter and make sure your php code is correct.

Comment: First get the root object..then extract array

Comment: uncomment this line and see what it prints `Log.e("testing", "json url value=" + json);`

Comment: ur response is wrong..u will have to apply a lot of tricks if you want to extract the data from above response..so it would be better to get ur response correct in proper jsonarray form with key value pair

Comment: is my php code correct

Comment: $services=mysql_query("select service_name from services"); $ser=''; while($fservices=mysql_fetch_array($services)) { $ser.=$fservices['service_name'].","; } $newser = explode($ser,","); print_r($newser); echo "<br/>".$ser."<br/>"; if(mysql_num_rows($services)) { $arr = array('result' => "sucess", 'data' => $ser, 'msg' => ' Sucessfull'); } else { $arr = array('result' => "error", 'msg' => 'Unsucessfull'); } echo json_encode($arr); ?>

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JSON response is wrong..

You need to generate response like this..

```
{"result":"sucess","data":[{"serv_name":"Painting service"},
{"serv_name":"Plumbing service"},{"serv_name":"Electrical service"},
{"serv_name":"Carpentry Services"},{"serv_name":"Aluminium works"},
{"serv_name":"House Cleaning"},{"serv_name":"Home Appliance"},
{"serv_name":"Glazing Cleaning"},{"serv_name":"Yard Maintenance"},
{"serv_name":"Water Tank Cleaning"},{"serv_name":"Electronics Services"},
{"serv_name":"Upholstery Services"},{"serv_name":"DRY CLEANERS"},
{"serv_name":""}],"msg":" Sucessfull"}
```

then you can parse the response using below code..

```
String responce = json.getString("data");
JSONObject servicejson = new JSONObject(responce);
JSONArray jArray = servicejson.getJSONArray("data");
System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jArray.length());
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String serviceName = json_data.getString("serv_name");
   Log.e("testing", "responce" + serviceName);
}
Log.e("testing", "responce" + responce);
```

Comment: $services=mysql_query("select service_name from services"); $ser=''; while($fservices=mysql_fetch_array($services)) { $ser.=$fservices['service_name'].","; } $newser = explode($ser,","); print_r($newser); echo "<br/>".$ser."<br/>"; if(mysql_num_rows($services)) { $arr = array('result' => "sucess", 'data' => $ser, 'msg' => ' Sucessfull'); } else { $arr = array('result' => "error", 'msg' => 'Unsucessfull'); } echo json_encode($arr); ?>

Comment: <?php

$services = mysql_query("select service_name from services");
$ser = '';
$arrJson = array();
while ($fservices = mysql_fetch_array($services)) {
    $data=$fservices['service_name'];
    $arrJson = array("serv_name", $data);
}

$arrJson1 = array("data", $arrJson);

if (mysql_num_rows($services)) {
    $arr = array('result' => "sucess", 'data' => $arrJson1, 'msg' => ' Sucessfull');
} 
else {
    $arr = array('result' => "error", 'msg' => 'Unsucessfull');
} 
echo json_encode($arr);

?>

Answer (score 0):

your data is `JSONArray` and you are passing it as `JSONObject` ...

```
public void parseJson(String json) {
    try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray root = obj.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject att = (JSONObject) root.getJSONObject(i);
                    // - your code- //
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```